# calculate area of polygon given in WGS84 coordinates

Tags: ruby, geospatial

In my Ruby on Rails app I get a GeoJSON containing polygons, so I basically get arrays of wgs84 coordinates like this:

```
[
  [
    8.414883613586426,
    51.75252652576658
  ],
  [
    8.414196968078613,
    51.74674780234288
  ],
  [
    8.42200756072998,
    51.748713979726574
  ],
  [
    8.42228651046753,
    51.752499958614976
  ],
  [
    8.414883613586426,
    51.75252652576658
  ]
]
```

Can somebody give an example, how I can accurately calculate the area of those polygons in km²? I know this question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937248/727341), but it's 4 years old, there is no example given and I don't quiet understand the library linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: check this gem https://github.com/DanielVartanov/ruby-geometry and also refer this http://codedmi.com/questions/2584628/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates it may help you.

Comment: As I understand it, both solutions require a flat coordinate system. Since I have WGS84 coordinates, I'd have to convert them to an area truthy projection (like Mollweide projection) to get "regular" coordinates.

But I don't think I'm the only on having this problem, so I'm convinced there is a simpler solution here that I'm missing. Maybe a gem that can do something like `WGS84Polygon(coordinates_array).area # => 54.3`